# Trouble solving an exercise on differential geometry involving the arc length function and its inverse

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, curves, inverse-function

Let $\alpha:I\to R^3$ be a regular parametrized curve (not necessarily by arc length) and let $\beta: J\to R^3$ be a reparametrization of $\alpha(I)$ by the arc length $s=s(t)$, measured from $t_0\in I$. Let $t=t(s)$ be the inverse function of $s$ and set $\frac {d\alpha}{dt}=\alpha'$, $\frac {d^2\alpha}{dt^2}=\alpha''$, etc. Prove that:

**a.** $\frac {dt}{ds}=\frac {1}{\vert \alpha'\vert}$

**My attempt at a solution:**

First, I renamed the function $t$ to $\tau$ to distinguish it from the real number $t$, and the real number $s$ to $l$ to distinguish it from the function $s$, to avoid mixing things up. That is:

$$s:I\to \mathbb R, \space s(t) = \int_{t_0}^t{\vert \alpha'(\sigma)\vert\space d\sigma}$$
$$\tau: J\to \mathbb R, \space \tau(l)=s^{-1}(l)$$

The derivative of $\tau$ at $l$ is:

$$\tau'(l)=(s^{-1})^{'}(l)=\frac {1}{s'(s^{-1}(l))}=\frac {1}{s'(\tau(l))}$$

The derivative of $s$ at $t$ is:

$$s'(t)=\vert\alpha'(t)\vert$$

Therefore:

$$\tau'(l)=\frac {1}{\vert\alpha(\tau(l))\vert}$$

The way the exercise is stated makes it seem like $\frac {dt}{ds}(x)=\frac {1}{\vert \alpha'(x)\vert}$ for every $x$, even though those two functions don't even have the same domain, while my solution states it as $\frac {dt}{ds}(x)=\frac {1}{\vert \alpha'(y)\vert}$, for $y=\tau(x)$. Is this a standard way of referring to derivatives and inverses of functions? I'm confused if my solution missed something or if I'm simply not understanding notation.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're being extra careful about notation, you most definitely should not write $\int_a^t f(t)\,dt$. That is horrid, using $t$ as a dummy variable and as another variable as well. You should have $\tau'(l) = 1/|\alpha'(\tau(l))|$. The standard formula is usually written as $\dfrac{dt}{ds}(s(t)) = \dfrac1{\frac{ds}{dt}(t)} = 1/|\alpha'(t)|$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, you're right, I'll adjust the integral to put it in a better form. As to the question, it seems like the author of the exercise used non-standard notation?

Comment: It’s unfortunately quite standard that people using Leibniz notation for derivatives omit the point at which the derivative is evaluated. Just think about all the “find $dy/dx$ exercises throughout calculus.

Comment: One thing you should be aware of about Leibniz notation is that it is based on the older idea of "related variables" and not the newer idea of "functions", even though we've shoehorned functions into the notation. To Leibniz, $\frac{dt}{ds}$ is an expression in the variable $s$, while $\frac{d\alpha}{dt}$ is an expression in the variable $t$. $t$ and $s$ are not independent variables - a value for one forces the value of the other. So one would evaluate $\frac{dt}{ds}$ at the value of $s$, and evaluate $\frac{d\alpha}{dt}$ at the associated value of $t$. The function composition is implicit.